# Microcontroller Interfacing with Stepper Motor - Current Consumption

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, motor, stepper-motor, motor-controller

I have this [MPC5606S](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MPC5606S.pdf) Microcontroller which I have interfaced with this Sonceboz [Bi polar Stepper Motor](https://www.sonceboz.com/sites/default/files/medias/standard-products/data-sheets/hybrid-stepper-motor/version2018/6540_13-4.0.pdf).
The Microcontroller is powered up by 5V and 3.3V and the Stepper motor interface is connected to the 5V Power domain.

I am a little new to this stepper motor working.

This is the connection between the Microcontroller and the stepper motor :

[image: Micro]

[image]

There is also another same stepper motor for the "SPEED" net but I am showing only for the Tacho net.

The input to the COS+, COS- pins of the Stepper are 15kHz, 50% duty cycle PWM Input and the rise time & fall time of the signals is in the order of 30ns-40ns

All I want to understand is the how to calculate - how much current does the motor consume during the normal condition? How to calculate the current consumption of this bipolar stepper motor which takes the current from the Microcontroller pins? I am trying to calculate the maximum output current of the Microcontroller through its output ports.

Comment: That stepper motor is not suitable for connecting to your microcontroller pins.  You need to add a stepper motor driver chip.

Comment: You will kill your micro. Kinda odd they don't have built in current limiting but that's a other issue.

Comment: How can you deduce that the stepper motor is not suitable to connect with the micro?

Comment: @newbie. According to the link, the coil resistance is rather low. Using Ohms law, calculate the current at 5V then compare that with the current rating of your microcontroller pin. I’m pretty sure the numbers will tell a compelling story.